# testContextInstant value is always Null when it was called from logger file to test case file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, vs-unit-testing-framework, testcontext

I have read some information regarding TestContext of MStest and can use it accordingly.

Now my task about TestContext is a little bit different and am confusing how it could work.

The situation related to three files:

1. In testcase.cs file, TestContext property is in [Test Class]. But in [TestMehtod], I don't want to use like testContextInstance.WriteLine("WRITE TEST PARAMETERS") directly, it will be put in another file named TestLogger.cs.

   ```
   [TestClass]
   public class Test1 : BaseTestTemplate
   {
       public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

       public static void FixtureSetUp(TestContext testContext)
       {
       }

       public static void FixtureTearDown(TestContext testContext)
       {
       }

       [TestInitialize]
       public override void SetUp()
       {
       }

       [TestMethod]
       {
           Logger.BeginSection("WRITE TEST PARAMETERS"); // instead of testContextInstance.WriteLine("WRITE TEST PARAMETERS");
       }
   }
   ```
2. In AssemblySetup.cs file, in [AssemblyInitialize], public static void AssemblySetUp(TestContext testContext) is done and it include one function that is InitializeLogging(); In this function, I initialize TestLogger with Logger.RegisterLogChannel(LogChannel.TestLog, new TestLogger()).

   ```
   [TestClass]
   public static class AssemblySetUpClass
   {
       public static void InitializeLogging()
       {
           string testContext = "";
           Logger.RegisterLogChannel(LogChannel.TestLog, new TestLogger(testContext));
      }

       [AssemblyInitialize]
       public static void AssemblySetUp(TestContext testContext)
       {
           InitializeLogging();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Following I add testContextInstance.WriteLine(title) in TestLogger.cs. But in debug, testContextInstance is always null.

   ```
   public sealed class TestLogger : LoggerBase
   {
       private TestContext testContextInstance;

       public TestLogger(string testContext)
       {
       }

       public override void BeginSection(string title)
       {
           testContextInstance.WriteLine(title);
           base.BeginSection(title);
       }
   }
   ```

I am trying to modify Logger.RegisterLogChannel(LogChannel.TestLog, new TestLogger(testContext)) The purpose is to tell TestLogger, testContext will be called. In TestLogger, I also add private TestContext testContextInstance; and public TestLogger(string testContext)

The problem is still the same, in Warning it said, testContextInstance is never assigned to, will always have its default value null

I hope you could understand my problem. Please give me some idea or solutions on how to handle with it, thank you very much.

Comment: It's hard to understand code just from a description.  Can you post the code for TestLogger?  And MSTestLogger, if that is a different class.  We don't need to see all of it, just the bits that are relevant.

Comment: ok,Ann,I have added the relevant code.thanks! And there is no MSTestLogger, only TestLogger, Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got this code:

```
 private TestContext testContextInstance;
 public TestLogger(string testContext)
 {
 }
```

Is the constructor to `TestLogger` really supposed to be empty?  The problem might be as simple as you never assigning your parameter `testContext` to anything in the constructor body.  I would assume that you're supposed to assign it to `testContextInstance` in the constructor.

```
 private TestContext testContextInstance;
 public TestLogger(string testContext)
 {
     testContextInstance = testContext;
 }
```

Comment: Yes,Ann,you are right,parameter testContext should be assigned in the constructor.Thank you very much!!!